# Is there a future replacement for thunderbird Yet?

Tags: 13.04, thunderbird, email, alternative

I have been thunderbird user even before was included in default apps. I have never loved Evolution and all alternative at that time were either not mature enough or single accounts.

Recentely I saw that Mozilla Thunderbird is lagging behind firefox (FF21 TB17) which is not a good sign to me and I thought its time to look for any alterative to start getting used to. I have five accounts and am not willing to use Web interface.

What is alternative that can handle multi account yet with bright future?

Comment: Why do you think Thunderbird is "lagging behind"? The latest release is [quite recent](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/17.0.6/releasenotes/): May 14, 2013. Version numbers are just numbers. One can't say that Google Chrome 27 is ahead of Firefox 21 just by judging from the numbers.

Comment: What makes you think Thunderbird is "lagging behind"?  The version number???  You do realise Thunderbird 17.0.6 was released like 3 weeks ago?

Comment: By the way, after Thunderbird 17 comes Thunderbird 24 according to the [Mozilla releases page](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Releases). "Next Thunderbird Major Release Thunderbird 24 Moves to RELEASE on Week of September 17, 2013"

Comment: Yeah but rumours from last year that Mozilla will abandoned TB and the lagging behind of versions worries me. Is there any word of assurance that Mozilla aren’t abandoning TB?

Comment: Considering that e-mail is a fairly mature internet service it should not come as a surprise that email clients are less often updated than, say web browsers. Web browser revisions are naturally driven by new technologies becoming available.

Comment: gertvdijk would you add that link of mozilla TB23 as answer. I would like to accept that one. It tears down my arguments to ashes :)

Comment: The reason I don't use firefox anymore is that they just race Chrome in version numbers instead of actually developing their browser. sad just sad.

Comment: Are people down-voting because I have explained my worries or what? Or do they expect all people knows all things? What is the point of Ask ubuntu then?
 Ah its their choice let them go ahead!

Comment: I would say that people are downvoting because you when you make statements like ~"TB is lagging behind" you really do need to cite your source. An Aunt Sally isn't a good platform on which to build a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Version numbers are just numbers

One can't say that Google Chrome 27 is ahead of Firefox 21 just by judging from the numbers. Likewise isn't Thunderbird 17 dead if there's a Firefox 21.

Note that Thunderbird is still [maintained](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/17.0.6/releasenotes/) and the latest release (17.0.6) was just a few weeks ago (May 14, 2013).

I do see what you mean though, as up to version 17 (from 5 on) has been in sync with Firefox and Gecko version numbers. [Wikipedia on Thunderbird](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Thunderbird#Releases) for example:

> Thunderbird development releases occur in three stages, called Beta, Earlybird and Daily, which correspond to Firefox's Beta, Aurora and Nightly stages. The release dates and Gecko versions are exactly the same as Firefox; for example, Firefox 7 and Thunderbird 7 were both released on September 27, 2011, and were both based on Gecko 7.0.

To me this is just a convention and version numbers don't necessarily mean anything just from the number.

#### After 17 will be 24

According to the current state of the [Mozilla.org Releases page](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Releases), the next Thunderbird stable release will be numbered 24 and is planned for release in the week of September 17, 2013.

Thunderbird 23 will be available in the beta channel in the week of June 24, 2013, but won't be released as stable as far as I can see.